# the use and the meaning of the verb 実感する in the given example

Tags: words, syntax

I would like to ask for help with translating the following sentence:

```
今日は、「練習していないことは嘘をつかない」という悲しいセリフを実感しました。練習も嘘をつかないんだけど、その逆も然り。
```

I understand parts of it for example

```
練習していないことは嘘をつかない
悲しい
セリフ
実感する
```

But my problem is putting them together in translation of the sentence above. Also, I found out that 実感する　means "have a feeling", "my actual feeling" is or "to realize", but I can't make it out which one is the right one here.

So basically, I have problem with the use of the verb 実感する, furthermore with the translation of the whole sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like

> 今日は、「練習していないことは嘘をつかない」という悲しいセリフを実感しました。
>   Today I experienced the sad line "the fact of not having practised doesn't lie" for myself.

If you gave some context there might be a more fitting translation.

Comment: Thank you for the help. so that sebiru may be an inner voice saying it to herself or himself.

Comment: "I you have not practised well, then the fact will be known to everyone even if you don't say about it" -- "You can't do good jobs without practises"

Answer (score 4):

It's something along the lines of:

> Today I realized what is really meant by the woeful words, "it shows when you have not practiced".  I know it shows when one has practiced; but, the opposite is also very true.

Basically, 実感 means that one has "actually (実) experienced/felt (感)" something.